# Animate UIImageView on UIBezierPath according to time iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I created infinity ♾ sign with `UIBezierPath` and animates sun view on same path. But I want to set sun view according to time on path. Sun view always start animating from initial point of `UIBezierPath`.

Following is the task I am unable to achieve:
- Whenever user enter in app I need to set sun view on `UIBezierPath` according to time and start animating from that particular point.

```swift
class LineDraw: UIView
{

    var path: UIBezierPath!

    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var circlePathSize:CGSize?
    let circleView = UIView()
    let sunImage = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
//        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)   {
        let height = self.frame.height
        let width = self.frame.width
        let heightFactor = height/4
        let widthFactor = width/4

        path = UIBezierPath()
        path.lineWidth = 3.0

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:widthFactor, y: heightFactor))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:widthFactor * 3, y: heightFactor * 3), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:widthFactor * 2, y: heightFactor), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:widthFactor * 2, y: heightFactor * 3))

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:widthFactor * 3, y: heightFactor * 3))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:widthFactor * 3, y: heightFactor), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:widthFactor * 4, y: heightFactor * 3), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:widthFactor * 4, y: heightFactor))

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:widthFactor * 3, y: heightFactor))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:widthFactor, y: heightFactor * 3), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:widthFactor * 2, y: heightFactor), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:widthFactor * 2, y: heightFactor * 3))

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:widthFactor, y: heightFactor * 3))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:widthFactor, y: heightFactor), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:0, y: heightFactor * 3), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:0, y: heightFactor))

        UIColor.purple.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
        animateCircleOnPath()
    }
    func animateCircleOnPath() {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position");
        animation.duration = 20.0
        animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
        sunImage.frame.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
        animation.path = path.cgPath
        sunImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Logo")
        self.addSubview(sunImage)
        sunImage.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

Current output

[image]

Comment: Hi. I think you forgot to mention what your issue is. Please tell us what is your current result and what is expected result.

Comment: @MaticOblak Thanks for your quick response, I am new on Stack Overflow. I am unable to achieve the points I mentioned as *Point to achieve* in original post. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit unclear but it seems like all you need to do is modify your `CAKeyframeAnimation`. Try something like the following:

```
let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position");
animation.duration = 24*60*60 // 24 hours
animation.timeOffset = {
    let date = Date() // Now
    let startDateComponents = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date()) // Describing components that will return start of this day
    let startDate = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.date(from: startDateComponents)!
    let endDate = date

    return endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
}()
```

So as you stated:

> Sun view will complete single loop in 24 hours.

We are setting duration to 24h `animation.duration = 24*60*60`. You should note that due to daylight savings it is possible for a day to have 23 hours or 25 hours. It is an edge case but it might be worth considering. So duration may be improved by using `animation.duration = todayEndDate.timeIntervalSince(todayStartDate)`. But the 24h should do for now.

and then

> Whenever user enter in app I need to set sun view on UIBezierPath
>   according to time and start animating from that particular point.

All that needs to be done is set a correct `timeOffset` which IF I assume correctly should be the duration within the current day; so at 13:23 that should be 13 hours and 23 minutes depending on your local time and calendar.

The tricky part here is "depending on your local time and calendar". So at the same time 2 people living in different parts of world would see the sun position at different location. Which makes sense I hope. So we need to retrieve the `Date` at which this day begun. So we use the following:

```
let startDateComponents = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
let startDate = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.date(from: startDateComponents)!
```

We need to use current `Date` and extract year, month and day from it (no hours and minutes). To do so we need to choose depending on who's perspective. To do so a `Calendar` with `TimeZone` is used. And `autoupdatingCurrent` is whatever the device is using.

We then use the same calendar to compose the `Date` back which should now as by default have hours, minutes, seconds... set to 0 which effectively returns as beginning of this day.

As we subtract the two dates (current and the one at beginning of this day) using time interval `timeIntervalSince` we get the duration that is needed for `timeOffset`.

I hope this clears it all.

Comment: Yeah, I got your concept of time. But the actual problem I am facing while setting the sun view CGPoint(x,y) on 'UIBezierPath' according to time, That how to get appropriate CGPoint(x,y) on 'UIBezierPath' according to time. Means I am unable to figure out that how to measure time on 'UIBezierPath' and get appropriate CGPoint to set to sun view and animation should start from that particular CGPoint not from initial point of 'UIBezierPath'. Currently animation starts from very initial point of 'UIBezierPath' every time user enters the app. Hope you got my point.

Comment: @gurwindersingh yes, this is done via `animation.timeOffset`. It seems to work for me. It starts on correct part of the animation. Did you try the code I posted?